# Doubts in the construction $\text{Cyc}(\mathcal{Z})$ from symbolic method Flajolet

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, analytic-combinatorics, combinatorial-species

It is easy to show that the generating function of the consecution $\text{Cyc}(\mathcal{Z})$ is $\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)$.

My question is, how to start from here to prove that the generating function for $\text{Cyc}_{\geq r}(\mathcal{Z})$  is

$$\sum_{n\geq r}(n-1)!\frac{z^n}{n!}=\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)-\sum_{n=1}^{r-1}\frac{z^n}{n}$$

I suppose that to pass to that expression I must do some algebraic step but I can't see it. ($\mathcal{Z}$ is a atomic class)

Comment: Did you mean $\sum_{n=1}^{r-1}\frac{x^n}{n}$, or (what I believe should be tha case) $\sum_{n=1}^{r-1}\frac{A(x)^n}{n}$?

Comment: If my second guess is correct, simply note that the generating function of ${\rm Cyc}_k(\mathcal{A})$ is $\frac{x^n}n$, so the generating function of ${\rm Cyc}_{\geq k}(\mathcal{A})$ is $\sum_{n\geq k}\frac{A(x)^n}n$, which evaluates to the corrected formula.

Comment: I just went through Flajolet's book again and I just noticed that I seem to have an error in the generating function

Comment: I still think the formula should be as I described; the generating function of ${\rm Cyc}_{\geq r}(\mathbb{Z})$ is $$C(z)=\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)-\sum_{n= 1}^{r-1}\frac{z^n}{n}$$

Comment: @C-RAM you are right, sorry, finger error

Comment: @C-RAM I already have the explanation clear, if you like write an answer to mark it as correct, but the key is to know generating function for $\text{Cyc}_k$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply note that the exponential generating function for ${\rm Cyc}_n(\mathcal{Z})$ is given by $$C_n(z)=(n-1)!\frac{z^n}{n!}=\frac{z^n}n$$
so the exponential generating function for ${\rm Cyc}_{\geq r}(\mathcal{Z})$ is given by
$$\sum_{n\geq r}C_n(z)=\sum_{n\geq r}\frac{z^n}{n}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{z^n}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{r-1}\frac{z^n}{n}=\log\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)
-\sum_{n=1}^{r-1}\frac{z^n}{n}$$
as desired.